# Deserialize List<BsonDocument> from JSON string

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to import the sample dataset in [this mongo tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/), but I am trying to do it using C# code. Here is what I have:

```
 var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\primer-dataset.json");
 string line;
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
     sb.Append(line);
 }

 var documents = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BsonDocument>>(sb.ToString());
 var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
 collection.InsertMany(documents);
```

I get the following error when I try to Deserialize the json string:

> Cannot deserialize a 'List' from BsonType 'Document'

I can't find anything online to tell what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Note: [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/import-data/) links to the example data set [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json). I don't know much about json but it appears to be invalid as there are multiple root elements. For it to be a `List<BsonDocument>>` I'm pretty sure there needs to be `[]` around the whole thing, then each record needs a comma to separate it. But this file comes directly from MongoDb's website as an example file so there must be another way to read it.

Comment: The answer appears to be explained [here](https://zaiste.net/2012/08/importing_json_into_mongodb/): "By default, monogoimport assumes a special structure for a file to import from: similar to JSON format except that only one document per line is allowed with no comma after each of them". The example file you have is *only* for [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), from the looks of it. To do your tests you can just copy the first X records to a new file, put `[]` around them and comma separate them. I think your command will work fine then.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (and your help). I got it to work by modifying the json file and parsing into a JArray, they looping through that and inserting into the collection. I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I had to modify the JSON document based on Quantic's comment. The sample doc assumes the user is going to use mongoimport to import the data. Once I added the necessary brackets and commas to make it a standard array, I was able to import it using the following C# code:

```
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
    var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\primer-dataset.json");
    string line;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       sb.Append(line);
    }

    var arr = JArray.Parse(sb.ToString());
    foreach(JObject o in arr)
    {
       var d = BsonDocument.Parse(o.ToString());
       collection.InsertOne(d);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever has the same problem. The solution is to add the brackets to json string before the parsing:

```
var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
json = "[" + json + "]";
            
var bsonDocuments = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(json);
if (bsonDocuments.Length > 0)
{
   await collection.InsertManyAsync(bsonDocuments);
}
```

Comment: this one is the best answer